# Android ListView MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, textview

I am trying to loop through my listView and hightlight the textviews and play the text being highlighted.

Problem is all the audio files play at a same time and highlight and unhighlight at a same time as well. and the whole app seems to feeeze while the audio gets played..

I know I have to use Threads maybe but still not sure how to this.

Here is my code

```
//This is how I call it 
Player  plOptions  =  new Player(sound,tf);
plOptions.start();

// this is the thread
private class Player extends Thread
{

    String sPlayerPath;
    TextView tf;

    public Player(String sPath_, TextView tv_) {

        sPlayerPath = sPath_;
        tf= tv_;         
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        final MediaPlayer mp =  new MediaPlayer();        
        try {

            mp.setDataSource(sPlayerPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                TextHighLight(tf);  

            }
        });

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                TextUnHighLight(tf);  
            }

        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the code in onListItemSelected to answer the question why all items are being played,highlighted at the same time.

But what I understand from what you did provide, is that you dont need a thread. just use prepareAsync() instead of prepare(), android will handle the threading for you.This will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: The code needs to play when a button i pressed not when an items is selected. So If I press play . A loop goes over each ListView Item highlights it and play the sound..

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your media player when in create method.Implement onCompletionListener event and provide the method to play the next song.In the next method reset the media player then it will work perfectly.

**for eg and some imp note:**

If you are clicking in the listview and the media file plays in another activity it will play multiple songs. for eg ActivityA contains ur list and ActivityB contains mediacontrols. In this case it will play multiple song to avoid this situation u must use service